# How to write React code to display data of the array object using useEffect

Tags: react-hooks

What I am trying:

1. Take a random character from the characters array and display its abilities and role
2. Take other four unique random chars name from the same array and display these as option.
3. Please note that the options must have the correct answer too
4. If the guessed character is correct the score should increase by 1 else decrease by 1

Code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "../styles/App.css";

const characters = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Jett",
    role: "Duelist",
    abilities: ["TailWind", "Cloud Burst", "UpDraft", "Blade Storm"],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Phoenix",
    role: "Duelist",
    abilities: ["HotHands", "Blaze", "Curve Ball", "Run It Back"],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Yoru",
    role: "Duelist",
    abilities: ["GateCrash", "Fakeout", "Blind Side", "Dimensional Drift"],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Reyna",
    role: "Duelist",
    abilities: ["Dismiss", "Leer", "Devour", "Empress"],
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Raze",
    role: "Duelist",
    abilities: ["Paint Shells", "Boom Bot", "BlastPack", "ShowStopper"],
  }
];

const App = () => {
  const [currChar, setCurrChar] = useState({
    name: "",
    role: "",
    abilities: [],
    options: [],
  });

  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);

  const changeChar = () => {
     
      }

  const scoreHandler = (e) => {
   
  };

  useEffect(() => {
   
  });
  return (
    <div id="main">
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="header">Guess the Character</h1>
        <div className="ques-area">
          <div className="score" id='score'>Score: {score}</div>
          <h3>The character has the following abilities:</h3>
          <h4>Role: {currChar.role}</h4>
          {currChar.abilities.join()}
          <div className="options">
            {currChar.options.map((option) => (
              <button   onClick={scoreHandler}>
                {option.name}
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the problem?
What have you done to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    useEffect(() => {
    getRandomObject(characters);
  }, []);
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const getRandomObject = (array) => {
    const optionArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      optionArr.push(array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]);
    }
    const randomObject = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
    const obj = {
      name: randomObject.name,
      role: randomObject.role,
      abilities: randomObject.abilities,
      options: optionArr.slice(0, 4)
    };
    setCurrChar(obj);
  };
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question was not great, but it is not clear here how this solves the problem. Could you explain, by way of an edit to the answer?

Comment: Actually, similar question was asked by this guy or somebody else with a bit modified question from this one there I have pasted the whole code. Here the problem is  how to send data to the state variables from the above given array and also on after every rander data should get randomly positioned. And there will be 4 buttons in the UI and onclicked on each of this button if the text value of button matched with the array items, score should be +1 else -1.

Comment: The question  is not that clear, but the guy has given the whole code so when I pasted it on code sandbox I got the clarity because much of the UI was already been build